# How to calculate p value of two images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, data-mining, probability, image-segmentation

I want to calculate p-value of my image comparison with ground truth image (reference image). So I find that we can calculate it from sensitivity and specificity value. Is it possible? Could you show me formula that apply for two images? Or any function in matlab?

Comment: If you are talking about p value of statistical testing, generally you need to have (assume) distribution (of the images in your case) In order to do that, you should analyze more data. With the estimated distribution of images, you can test your hypothesis and calculate p value. This is all I can say based on information you have given.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin: Thank you. That means we can not calculate p value of two binary images, right? Because p value indicates reliability of method. So I try to calculate them instead of sensitivity and specificity

Comment: I found matlab has one function that is ttest2 can do it. Do you use it

Answer (score 0):

p-values only make sense when you can model the *statistical distribution* of data.

In order to compute the p-value, first compute the c.d.f.:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

If you cannot compute a c.d.f. for your problem (I am not aware of how one could compute c.d.f.s for images, don't ask me about this!), you won't be able to compute a p-value either.